# Is there a clean way to assign partial values to masked array in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

First, see example codes below:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(100)
ma = (a > 10)

# for some reason, I need to assign values to first 10 elements of the masked array a.
a[ma][0:10] = -999
```

However, it is obvious this could not change the values inside array `a`. And finally I accomplished it by introduce another mediator array `b = a[ma]`. For instance:

```
b = a[ma]
b[0:10] = -999
a[ma] = b

In [110]: a
Out[110]:
array([   0,    1,    2,    3,    4,    5,    6,    7,    8,    9,   10,
   -999, -999, -999, -999, -999, -999, -999, -999, -999, -999,   21,
     22,   23,   24,   25,   26,   27,   28,   29,   30,   31,   32,
     33,   34,   35,   36,   37,   38,   39,   40,   41,   42,   43,
     44,   45,   46,   47,   48,   49,   50,   51,   52,   53,   54,
     55,   56,   57,   58,   59,   60,   61,   62,   63,   64,   65,
     66,   67,   68,   69,   70,   71,   72,   73,   74,   75,   76,
     77,   78,   79,   80,   81,   82,   83,   84,   85,   86,   87,
     88,   89,   90,   91,   92,   93,   94,   95,   96,   97,   98,
     99])
```

Actually in my complex case, the array `a` could be very large. So it spend memory spaces a lot. Is there an clean way to do that?

Comment: I marked this as duplicate because I just spent time answering a similar question.  Basically you have to modify the `ma` mask.  Converting it to an index array is easiest, though modifying the boolean array itself is possible.

Comment: It's in the duplicate bar, as well as the side bar.